# Lookups and links on subgrids do not work after the CRM 2011 form opens with a custom page via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I could hardly explain the problem. 
I'll start from the beggining. My colleague has writtеn aspx page with the connection to CRM 2011. This page was writte to integrate CRM 2011 of our organization and call center. 
It is possible to open selected Contact. It's made with the help of java script

```
   window.open("http://<server>/<orgname>/main.aspx?etc=2&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d2%26etc%3d2%26id%3d%257b" + id + "%257d%26pagemode%26rskey%26preloadcache%3d862423166&pagetype=entityrecord", "Contact", params);
```

All had been working fine till yesterday. We have updated our CRM 2011 to Rollup 6, then 10 and 11.

Today the day started with next unbelievable bug.
When operator clicks on the button that opens Contact form, it opens but you can't pass to any lookup or open some linked objects in subgrids. 
Most worryingly, that it only happens on prodact server on the local machine there is no such problem. (On the test I can't reproduce this functionality right now(()

Even if you update the form several times, you can not open any linked object form from this Contact. But if you copy paste url to another windows, all works fine.
I have no idea what to do.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

The main reason is this simple line of CRM's native code.

```
masterWindow().preloadPage($v_2)
```

I'm opening CRM form from my custom page, and there is no function preloadPage in my code (in master window). For some stupid reasons you don't get this error while updating CRM form and even while debug. But if you press the button "Add new call" (Добавление -> Звонок) (or something like that sorry I haven't english CRM on hand) on the tab "Add" (Добавление) You could see this error.

The solve is simple too, just add dummy function on your page

```
    function preloadPage(UnusedValue) {

        // Ignore

    }
```

and everything will be fine.
Thanks for support!!!